# Publishing WPF application with a LINQ to class database

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, linq

I have a WPF application holding a LINQ to class database, now I need to publish this application to work on client's machine.
I have done this but it doesn't work like if the database was not found, I think my problem is that the database is not included in the deployed files, so I need help with a clear steps to publish my application including my database.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if you have online database it would be easy to deploy your application  with few steps using InstallShild or any featured tools   , otherwise this it would take more steps to adjust your client machine  .

Comment: Well, It's local database.

Comment: Now what is the steps to prepare client's machine?

Comment: You need to give more information about what kind of database you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL server database through LINQ to class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to interact with your `.mdf` database without having `SQL Server engine` installed on your client machine .

**Try this:**

- Install [SQL server Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx) on your Client machine
- Attach database to the SQL Server (using .mdf or using a DB backup)
- then change your connection string before deploying the application in client machine.

if you've hard coded the connection string then , you'll  have to change the connection string to adjust client's machine name , or add you connection string  inside `app.config` in order to give you the flexibly to modify it after deployment .

**App.Config:**

```
<configuration>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=OmidPayamak;IntegratedSecurity=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**using**

```
var connection = ConnectionFactory.GetConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Test"].ConnectionString, DataBaseProvider);
```

---

wish it help .